# python ThreadPoolExecutor: after submit a task, will the thread die if task failed?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

my question is: if the function of check_running_job raise an exception and didn't catch it up in check_running_job,  will it cause the thread running check_running_job die? So if I have max workers as 3, after it dies, then only 2 threads can serve future request?

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = setting.parallelism_of_job_checking) as te:
        while True:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = fetch_rows_as_dict(cursor)
            for x in result:
                id = x["id"]
                te.submit(check_running_job, id,)
            time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThreadPoolExecutor threads complete cleanly *either* by finishing their task or by raising an exception; a raised exception won't block the thread or prevent another worker from being assigned to it, and will cleanly set `.done()` to True just as if the task had finished correctly.

(You're probably aware of this, but if you try to access the `.return()` method of a task that has failed, its exception will be raised - so accessing the return value should always be done in a `try ... except` structure. If your code needs to know whether a task completed successfully or failed, this is one way of doing so.)